# check column exists in table and add column in one query

Tags: mysql

I want check, exists or not in mytable column "auto", and if not exists, add his. a make this so:

```
  mysql-> SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable
```

after, with PHP I check, in result exists or not "auto" and if no, I make:

```
  mysql-> ALTER TABLE mytable  ADD auto  VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Question: please tell, how to make this in one query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define following query in your stored procedure and call the stored procedure to add the column if not exist.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME='auto' AND TABLE_NAME='my_table' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='the_schema'
    )
    THEN
        ALTER TABLE `the_schema`.`my_table`
        ADD COLUMN `auto` VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

END IF;
```

Comment: IF / END IF is for stored programs only, it will not run as a standalone sql script - or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

just skip the first query, and try to add it, if its alredy exists, its going to fail, and if its missing, its going to be added

Comment: Ok thanks, but for example is this case: Must check column "auto", and if his not exists, add table column "some_column.